# Tengo un problema - Como respaldar un archivo .sql a una ruta especifica con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, rutas

necesito su ayuda. Necesito almacenar /respaldar con la carpeta "respaldos", dentro esta el archivo con el nombre de la base de datos y la fecha por ejemplo "domesa_sync3_07_07_2022", trate de codificar en varias maneras me da mensajes de error. Asi que necesito su ayuda, les dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
/**
* Respaldar base de datos de MySQL con PHP
* Función modificada de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284229/5032550
*
* Visita: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/10/22/script-respaldar-base-de-datos-mysql-php/
*/

// Ejemplo de llamada: exportarTablas("localhost", "root", "123", "foo");

function exportarTablas($host, $usuario, $pasword, $nombreDeBaseDeDatos)
{
set_time_limit(3000);
$tablasARespaldar = [];
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $pasword, $nombreDeBaseDeDatos);
$mysqli->select_db($nombreDeBaseDeDatos);
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$tablas = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
while ($fila = $tablas->fetch_row()) {
    $tablasARespaldar[] = $fila[0];
}
$contenido = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\";\r\nSET time_zone = \"+00:00\";\r\n\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\r\n/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\r\n--\r\n-- Database: `" . $nombreDeBaseDeDatos . "`\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n";
foreach ($tablasARespaldar as $nombreDeLaTabla) {
    if (empty($nombreDeLaTabla)) {
        continue;
    }
    $datosQueContieneLaTabla = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `' . $nombreDeLaTabla . '`');
    $cantidadDeCampos = $datosQueContieneLaTabla->field_count;
    $cantidadDeFilas = $mysqli->affected_rows;
    $esquemaDeTabla = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $nombreDeLaTabla);
    $filaDeTabla = $esquemaDeTabla->fetch_row();
    $contenido .= "\n\n" . $filaDeTabla[1] . ";\n\n";
    for ($i = 0, $contador = 0; $i < $cantidadDeCampos; $i++, $contador = 0) {
        while ($fila = $datosQueContieneLaTabla->fetch_row()) {
            //La primera y cada 100 veces
            if ($contador % 100 == 0 || $contador == 0) {
                $contenido .= "\nINSERT INTO " . $nombreDeLaTabla . " VALUES";
            }
            $contenido .= "\n(";
            for ($j = 0; $j < $cantidadDeCampos; $j++) {
                $fila[$j] = str_replace("\n", "\\n", addslashes($fila[$j]));
                if (isset($fila[$j])) {
                    $contenido .= '"' . $fila[$j] . '"';
                } else {
                    $contenido .= '""';
                }
                if ($j < ($cantidadDeCampos - 1)) {
                    $contenido .= ',';
                }
            }
            $contenido .= ")";
            # Cada 100...
            if ((($contador + 1) % 100 == 0 && $contador != 0) || $contador + 1 == $cantidadDeFilas) {
                $contenido .= ";";
            } else {
                $contenido .= ",";
            }
            $contador = $contador + 1;
        }
    }
    $contenido .= "\n\n\n";
}
$contenido .= "\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;";

# Se guardará dependiendo del directorio, en una carpeta llamada respaldos
$carpetafrom = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mod_dep_back\respaldos\ ';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');

$to = 'C:\Users\LGARAVITO\Desktop\ ';

// Validar primero si existe y es directorio
if (!file_exists($to) || !is_dir($to)) {
    // Verifica que realmente se creó la carpeta
    if (!mkdir($to, 0777, true)) {
        die("No se puede crear la carpeta $to");
    }
}
exec("copy $carpetafrom \"$to\" /Y");

# Calcular un ID único
$id = uniqid();

# También la fecha
$fecha = date("Y-m-d");

# Crear un archivo que tendrá un nombre como respaldo_2018-10-22_asd123.sql
$nombreDelArchivo = sprintf('%s/domesa_sync3_%s.sql', $carpetafrom, $fecha, $id);

#Escribir todo el contenido. Si todo va bien, file_put_contents NO devuelve FALSE
return file_put_contents($nombreDelArchivo, $contenido) !== false;
}

exportarTablas("localhost", "root", "", "domesa_sync3");

?>
```

El codigo es muy grande solo mire en la parte de $carpetafrom, de ahi es donde debe permitir guardar con ruta absoluta pero me muestra con error que la carpeta ya existe pero ironicamente no esta creado la carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, que alguien me de consejo o solución para ver que caí en el codigo fuente. Es breve, se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente se deba a los últimos caracteres de la ruta, por alguna razón en Windows `file_exists` e `is_dir` retornarán siempre falso para la ruta `$to`. Usa `$to = 'C:\Users\LGARAVITO\Desktop';`.

Comment: ah, OK gracias, ya resolví ese pequeño detalle  que me permite respaldar a otro sitio. Muchas gracias